# SchedulerException :JobStore class 'com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore' could not be instantiated

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have upgraded the spring boot from 2.2.5 RELEASE to 2.7.3 but getting below error

```
SchedulerException :JobStore class 'com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore' could not be instantiated.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: JobStore class 'com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore' could not be instantiated.
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:881) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:?]
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1579) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar:?]
```

war file deployed successfully on wildfly server but Quartz getting failed, we are using mongodb 4.2 , java 1.8 , quartz scheduler version 2.3.2, novemberain.quartz.mongo 2.0.0

Please help me

Regards,
Vijay Kumbharkar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That particular error says to me that you have specified that you want to use the `com.novemberain.quartz.mongodb.MongoDBJobStore` class to represent your job store (you want to store your jobs in MongoDB), but you haven't made that class available on the classpath.  Could it be that you are missing the maven or gradle statement that brings in the package that contains that class?  That's usually why you get that sort of error from Spring.

Comment: We have added external dependency and  also tried adding in pom.xml file  with org.quartz.scheduler version 2.2.0 but getting same error

Comment: Issue resolved , thanks !                                                                                                    
   Unable to download quartz-mongodb-2.2.0-rc2.jar  from Maven repository  getting forbidden error 403 . I have added manually jar  extracting the war file and added the same jar file with the help of 7zip and issue resolved.

Comment: Or You can use also below dependency: <dependency>
    <groupId>io.fluidsonic.mirror</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-rc2</version>
</dependency>